# How to calculate an factorial with loops in java

Tags: java, loops, factorial

I'm trying to write a portion of a program that calculates factorials using loops. I don't have any error messages, but I'm not getting any output.

Are there suggestions for my approach or is there a better approach using loops? Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorial {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Enter a non-negative number that you wish to perform a factorial function on: ");

    //Create scanner object for reading user input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Declare variables
    int number = input.nextInt();
    int factTotal = 1;

    //Execute factorial
    do{
        factTotal = factTotal * number;
        number--;
        while (number >= 1);
    }
    while (number <= 0);{
        System.out.println("That's not a positive integer!");
    }

    System.out.print(factTotal);
}
```

}

Comment: *"I don't have any error messages, but I'm not getting any output."* - Try using a debugger!

Comment: `while (number >= 1);` is the same as `while (number >= 1) { /*do nothing*/ }`, and will run forever.

Comment: Since calculation of factorial means to multiply positive numbers, what is `while (number <= 0)` supposed to do? Looping while `number` is negative doesn't seem to have any place in this code.

Comment: @Andreas - I added the final while statement for the sake of usability - in the case a user enter a negative integer they'll be notified that they've entered an invalid input. Is there a better way to do this? Would an if statement be better?

Comment: @Pernicious Yes, an `if` statement is better. Or a loop, if it loops back to prompt the user again.

Comment: @Pernicious Would you accept the best answer? It is bad practice to leave open questions when the issue has been resolved.

Comment: Oops! Will do, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way I would approach the factorial portion of your problem. I would do away with the do/while loops because it appears that you are getting stuck in an infinite loop if you aren't getting output.

```
//Call this method when you want to calculate the factorial
public int factorial(int num){
   for(int i = num-1; i > 1; i--){
       num *= i;
   }
   return num;
}
```

This is what it would look like in your code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorial {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Enter a non-negative number that you wish to perform a factorial function on: ");

    //Create scanner object for reading user input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Declare variables
    int number = input.nextInt();
    int factTotal = 1;

    if(number > 0){

        factTotal = factorial(number);

        System.out.print(factTotal);
   }
   else
       System.out.println("This is a negative number");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Pernicious, Please see your program with slight modifications and my comments added. I think this is what you were trying to do.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorial {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Enter a non-negative number that you wish to perform a     factorial function on: ");

    //Create scanner object for reading user input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Declare variables
    int number = input.nextInt();
    int factTotal = 1;

// The input number check should be before factorial calculation
    if(number <= 0){
        System.out.println("That's not a positive integer!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    //Execute factorial
    do {
        factTotal = factTotal * number;
        number--;
// while (number >= 1); This while should be after do{}, not within do{}
    } while (number >= 1);
//        This check should be done immeduately after user input, not after calculation of factorial.
//        while (number <= 0);
//        {
//            System.out.println("That's not a positive integer!");
//        }

    System.out.println(factTotal);
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code, in the `do...while` loop, you have used this `while` statement:

```
while (number >= 1);
```

Did you not notice the semicolon? And what is the point of this loop? Currently it is leading to an infinite loop as the value of `number` never changes and thus you are getting no output. 
 Also, your second `while` loop should much rather be an `if` statement as shown below
That piece of code is equivalent to:

```
while (number >= 1)
{
   //doNothing
}
```

I believe you meant to do:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorial {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Enter a non-negative number that you wish to perform a factorial function on: ");

    //Create scanner object for reading user input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Declare variables
    int number = input.nextInt();
    int factTotal = 1;

    //Execute factorial
    do{
        factTotal = factTotal * number;
        number--;
    }
    while (number <= 1);
    if(number < 0)
    {
         System.out.println("That is not a positive integer");
    }
    else
    System.out.print(factTotal);
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117502/discussion-between-skorrloregaming-productions-and-vaibhav-bajaj).